# check if line is empty between 2 lines(string)

Tags: batch-file

Thanks.

I have a log file, which contains the command results like this(pattern)

```
-----  Opening connection to: 10.4.2.1 at 13:35:07.49 -----  

Passed

-----  Closing connection to: 10.4.2.1 at 13:35:26.54 -----  


-----  Opening connection to: 10.4.28.17 at 13:35:07.49 -----  

Failed

-----  Closing connection to: 10.4.28.17 at 13:35:45.50 -----  


-----  Opening connection to: 10.4.24.15 at 13:35:07.49 -----  


-----  Closing connection to: 10.4.24.15 at 13:36:27.85 -----


-----  Opening connection to: 10.4.4.5 at 13:35:07.49 -----  


-----  Closing connection to: 10.4.4.5 at 13:36:27.85 -----
```

Am trying to get the server list which has empty line between (Opening/Closing connection to pattern)

so far am able to do this which gets only last entry of the result file

code :

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
color 9E
title Tool
SET "sourcedir=C:\Logs\"
SET "destdir=C:\Logs\"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "Opening connection to"^<"%sourcedir%\Results.log" ') do set /a start=%%a
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "Closing connection to"^<"%sourcedir%\Results.log" ') do set /a end=%%a
(
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%sourcedir%\Results.log" ') do (
 IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a leq %end% ECHO(%%b
 )
)>"%destdir%\FailedList.log"
GOTO :EOF
```

So in the FailedList.log, I should see only ip details

```
10.4.24.15
10.4.4.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code get the output you want when the input data have the pattern of your example data:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "ip="
(for /F "tokens=1,5" %%a in (Results.log) do (
   if "%%b" equ "!ip!" echo !ip!
   set "ip=%%b"
)) > FailedList.log
```

Comment: Thanks Aacini. that was perfect for me.